# how can I load a div into bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I know this is the basic question, but I'm not able to solve this. Please do help me.

I'm trying to load the content of div on a click of a hyperlink into the bootstrap modal. How can I able to do this?

Below is my code :

```
<a id="myModalId" href="#">myLink1</a>
<a id="myModalId" href="#">myLink2</a>
```

my modal structure:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" >
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- I would like my div content here -->
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and here's my div structure:

```
<div>
<div id="d1" style="display:none">
    div1 content                    
</div>
<div id="d2" style="display:none">
    div 2 content   
</div>
```

and modal calling function:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#myModalId').click(function(){
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });
            });
```

.
There are few such links and for each link I wold like to load a separate div using only single modal.
Can we do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use this function to load content in order by the clicked button link:

Buttons:

```
<a href="#myModalId" data-toggle="modal" data-content="d1">myLink1</a>
<a href="#myModalId" data-toggle="modal" data-content="d2">myLink2</a>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" >
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div id="d1" class="display-none">
                     div1 content                    
                  </div>
                  <div id="d2" class="display-none">
                     div 2 content   
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#myModalId').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget), // here is the button clicked
      content = button.data('content'), // here you can get information of the button
      modal = $(this); // Here is the modal

  modal.find('#'+content).slideDown('fast');
});
```

CSS:

```
.display-none{
    display: none;
}
```

You can review this method in the boostrap documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Regards!

Comment: Thank you for the help, but unfortunately  it doesn't work.                                  content of first div is loading for every link I clicked. Not able to figure out where I went wrong. any suggestion on this ?                                                 Thank you again

Comment: Hi, i change my code, in the div content i added a class display none and in jquery I change the function show() for slideDown(), review it and let me know if work's for you, regards!

Comment: Hello Sir, issue still exits. but it is working only in the case of page reload. I can see div 2 content after reload but right after clicking link 1, if I click link 2, div 1 content appears.                                                                                - Thank you

Comment: I guess " content = button.data('content') " is giving same value even though I click different links before reloading the page.

Comment: before this line: modal.find('[id="'+ content +'"]').slideDown('fast'); use an alert like this: alert(content); to check the value

Comment: Or change the line: modal.find('[id="'+ content +'"]').slideDown('fast'); for modal.find('#'+content).slideDown('fast');

Comment: Hi sir, able to see correct value for 'content' variable when I used alert. but not able to load the actual data of that div. I changed the line too as mentioned.

Comment: Hello, Can anyone please help me with this issue ?